# Does a click through from a google search get counted in analytics if the page dosnt load due to the server being down?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search

I was wandering does google count a click though and credit it to your analytics account if a user finds you in search, clicks through but the server is busy / slow for what ever reason,
So the user leaves before the page is loaded, dose google still credit your analytics count witha click through ?

I know that the tracking code dosnt load beacuse when you go the view source there is nothing there.. but dose google still credit your analytics account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I know that the tracking code dosnt load beacuse when you go the view
>   source there is nothing there."

You answered your own question. This is because Google Analytics happens in JavaScript, not server-side. The webserver has no idea that Google is tracking the pages, but rather the browser is telling Google that **it** visited your site. If the server is unable to serve the pages, then the script will not load, and the browser has no idea to tell Google that it visited the site.

Edit:
You could perhaps be looking for http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/ if you aren't aware of it already. This bypasses the browser and tells Google Analytics when the page is *processed*. May or not be reliable.